# PHP daemon shows status of "stopped" - can't run php script in the background

Tags: linux, php, command-line-interface, background-process

I'm trying to launch a PHP script in the background (Linux/Centos 6.8) by appending the & symbol to the command. However, 'jobs' lists the script with status [1]+ Stopped.
Issuing a 'bg 1' to run the script in the background still results in a "[1]+ Stopped" output.

I can issue 'fg 1' and the script runs in the foreground with no problems.

What am I doing wrong?

I am piping both stdout and stderr to files using > output.txt 2> error.txt

The script issues some shell commands including wget.

Thanks for any info to clarify this.

Comment: What have you done with standard input? Contact the script's developer and let them know of the problem.

Comment: The script needs no input.  I am the script developer. :)

Comment: Something needs input, otherwise the script would continue running.

Comment: It doesn't read from stdin at all. It simply runs wget to retrieve some security camera images directly to files. Would wget be causing this?

Comment: It looks like wget is the culprit.   If I create another script to simply write the numbers 1-60 to the stdout, sleeping 1 second between each, it works fine.

Comment: What is wget doing to suspend the script?  I can launch it in the foreground and it runs fine, never stops to wait on user input, and never displays anything to the screen.  I can tail the log file and it continues to grow as it should.